# how to sum up values from oracle database into java?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I have a java application which is connected to an Oracle database. I have a form where the user enters an ID called `COMMUNITY_ID`, a start date called `START_DATE` and an end date called `END_DATE`.

I want the application to search through the table in database for the entered values, and when the search result is correct I want it to display the sum of total values.

I have three methods; each method is responsible for searching a single text box. For example, the first method `total 1` searches for the `COMMUNITY_ID`, and the second method searches for the `START_DATE` and the last one searches for the `END_DATE`.

I get an error message saying the result set is empty or closed. I am not sure why because I dont understand the message clearly.

The following is my code.  If anyone has idea how to fix it that, please help me.

```
public void total3()
{
    ResultSet result;
    System.out.println("total 3");

    String endDate = this.EndTxtBox.getText();

    try
    {
        rs=st.executeQuery("select RECIPT_ID,COMMUNITY_ID,VALUE,START_DATE,END_DATE, ITEM_BOUGHT,REASON from RECIPTS where  END_DATE = '" +endDate+"'");
        //display();
        this.EndTxtBox.setText(rs.getString("END_DATE"));
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Searched Failed" + ex);
    }

    try
    {
        result =  rs=st.executeQuery("select SUM(VALUE)from RECIPTS where END_DATE = '" +endDate+"'" );
        //result =  rs=st.executeQuery("select RECIPT_ID,COMMUNITY_ID,VALUE,START_DATE,END_DATE, ITEM_BOUGHT,REASON,SUM(VALUE)from RECIPTS group by RECIPT_ID,COMMUNITY_ID,VALUE,START_DATE,END_DATE, ITEM_BOUGHT,REASON ");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error" + ex);
    }
}
```

Any ideas, please? What is wrong with it?

Comment: Just because you don't understand the message doesn't mean it's not helpful. Maybe *we* could understand it. Paste the complete stack trace.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to read from the result set before going to its first row:

```
if (rs.next()) {
    endDate = rs.getString("END_DATE");
}
```

Your code is full of bad practices:

- mixing UI code with database access code
- catching Exception
- selecting a whole lot of rows and columns when you're only interested by one of them
- not using prepared statements
- using both `result` and `rs` for the same thing
- not closing statements and result sets
- using String variables to store dates
- poor and inconsistent indentation